Homomorphic Encryption from LWE (Gentry) - Error Bounds
I am reading Gentry2013. He describes on page 10 under descryption, that $v_i \in (q/4, q/2]$. Later he describes that this ensures that the error does not grow outside of $q/2$ such that the plaintext $\mu'$ can be recovered.
I am wondering if the index $i$ is fixed or arbitrary, because for some specific $i=0$ and any $q>5$ the corresponding $v^i$ is not contained in the interval anymore.
On page 5 he describes further in the subsection Homomorphic Operations that

the secret key $\mathbf{v}$ is a $N$-dimensional vector over $\mathbf{Z}_q$ with at least one "big" coefficient $v_i$.

Does he fix the index $i$ here, such that all ongoing descriptions such as decryption

$\mu' = \left\lfloor \frac{x_{i}}{vi} \right\rceil$

refer to that very specific $i$? Is then the $i$ chosen such that $2^i$ falls in the range $(q/4, q/2]$? Or is my understanding completely off here? I have a hard time to follow the details in that paper.
